# Stop user from viewing page if condition is not met

Tags: php

Hi appologies if this has been answered but I can not find a clear answer for my question.

Lets say I have 2 pages, called `fruit.php` and `salad.php`

when user has entered data into fields for `fruit.php` he will be directed to salad.php however nothing prevents the user from typing `salad.php` into his browser which will open up second page and give wrong results because his data from page1, `fruit.php` has not been entered.

Any idea how I can stop user from accesing `salad.php` before fruit.php is completed?

Comment: Show your attempts..

Comment: Post your form please.

Comment: @NarendraSisodia Im just looking for logic to start to tackle this problem not code

Comment: @Marilee you can use `$_SESSION` Manual : http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in such case you can do something like this:
since the user is expected to enter some values in the 1st page so a (form) will be presenced there, let's say this one:

fruit.php

```
<form name="fruit" id="fruit" action="salad.php" method="POST">
First component: <input type="text" name="component1">
Second component: <input type="text" name="component2">
<input type="submit" value="check">
</form>
```

now the second page:

salad.php

```
<?php
//first thing first, we're going to check whether the user
//is being redirected by the form by doing something like
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
//do something
} else {
//this thing will redirect the user to the former page in case no form was applied
header('Location: fruit.php') or die('Unexpected error');
}
?>
```

I hope this would assist you, there are many ways and you always are recommended to check the (empty(field)) before processing any data to avoid unpleasant results

Answer (score 1):

Let's say fruit.php send a data in `get` like so

```
salad.php&donut=yummy
```

What you want, is when you load your salad.php , to verify if **donut** has been send. You need to use `isset()` for that purpose. (Note that this works too with `$_POST`, but for the sake of the example, i'm going to stick with `$_GET`)

```
if (isset($_GET['donut'))
//Good, your script has been called from fruit.php 
else 
//Nope ! He tried to type the adress in the browser ! Let's serve him an empty page here.
```

For the start this should do the trick, after that i'd suggest looking at `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` and after that maybe checking `$_session`.
And there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a salad.php in such a way that it accepts only POST request, in case of GET request, redirect it to fruit.php

Answer (score 0):

at the top of salad.php:

```
if(($_SESSION['HTTP_REFERER'] !="http://domain.ext/dir/fruit.php") || (!isset($_POST['essentialFormVar1From_fruit.php'])) || ...){
  header('location: http://domain.ext/dir/fruit.php');
};
else{
  ...
  //render page
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the values by POST you can verify in the "salad.php" page like that:

```
if(!isset($_POST['myVariable'])) {
    header('Location: fruit.php');
    exit;
}

... continue my salad page ...
```

If you are using GET, just change $_POST to $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

You could add into your salad.php a check if the correct data from a Request is sent:

```
if($_POST['fieldname'] == ''){
  echo 'you enterd the page wrong. Please go back to the <a href="...">Form</a> and enter the data needed';
}else{
  // normal page content here.
}
```

Thus the viewer will only get the page, when he submitted a fitting request.